# The lyricsForName function does not print anything

Tags: swift

The `lyricsForName` function does not print anything. The `shortNameFromName` does work and I have checked what's wrong with the second function.

```
func shortNameFromName(name : String) ->String{
    var shortName = ""

    let lowercaseNmae = name.lowercased()
    let vowelSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")
    if let range = lowercaseNmae.rangeOfCharacter(from: vowelSet, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
    {
        shortName = name.substring(from: range.lowerBound)
    }

    return shortName
}

func lyricsForName(lyricsTemplate : String , fullName : String) ->String{
    let bananaFanaTemplate = ["<FULL_NAME>, <FULL_NAME>, Bo B<SHORT_NAME",
                            "Banana Fana Fo F<SHORT_NAME>",
                             "Me My Mo M<SHORT_NAME>",
                             "<FULL_NAME>"].joined(separator: "\n")
    let shortName = shortNameFromName(name: fullName)
    let lyrics = lyricsTemplate
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<FULL_NAME>", with: fullName)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<SHORT_NAME>", with: shortName)

    print(lyricsForName(lyricsTemplate:bananaFanaTemplate , fullName: "vishnu"))

    return lyrics
}
```

1st function works perfectly but I guess 2nd function not working properly. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Hi there- is your function supposed to be recursive (you are calling lyricsForName from within the function declaration)? What happens if you print lyrics instead?

Comment: Its not supposed to be recursive

Comment: I took that function outside now it only prints a \n,same result when i try to print lyrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm at my desk now so took a quick look at your code. This now works (note the typo in bananaFanaTemplate):

```
func shortNameFromName(name : String) ->String{
     var shortName = ""

     let lowercaseNmae = name.lowercased()
     let vowelSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")
     if let range = lowercaseNmae.rangeOfCharacter(from: vowelSet, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive) {
          shortName = name.substring(from: range.lowerBound)
     }

     return shortName
 }

 func lyricsForName(lyricsTemplate : String , fullName : String) -> String {

     let shortName = shortNameFromName(name: fullName)
     let lyrics = lyricsTemplate
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "<FULL_NAME>", with: fullName)
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "<SHORT_NAME>", with: shortName)

     print(lyrics)

     return lyrics
 }

 let bananaFanaTemplate : String = ["<FULL_NAME>, <FULL_NAME>, Bo B<SHORT_NAME>",
                               "Banana Fana Fo F<SHORT_NAME>",
                               "Me My Mo M<SHORT_NAME>",
                               "<FULL_NAME>"].joined(separator: "\n")

 print(lyricsForName(lyricsTemplate:bananaFanaTemplate , fullName: "vishnu"))
```

Output:

vishnu, vishnu, Bo Bishnu
Banana Fana Fo Fishnu
Me My Mo Mishnu
vishnu

I think you are quite confused on the issue of function scope. You declared the constant bananaFanaTemplate inside your implementation of the function, where that parameter should have been passed in to the function. Likewise, you called the function from inside the function body, which you don't generally do unless it is supposed to be a recursive function.

Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Hope that helps.